# devicepolicymanager.isAdminActive() does not return true in Android O

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-8.0-oreo

Hi I am newbie to Android programming. 
But I have an intern helping me to build an app which can display BT MAC address and details Kernel version.

Based on my limitted understanding, we will need to get the `if (devicepolicymanager.isAdminActive(name1))` to `return true` then only we can access the BT MAC address and its kernel version.

But we found out the `if (devicepolicymanager.isAdminActive(name1))` does not `return true` in Android O.

Is there anyway to access the BT MAC address and Kernel version in Android O?